# What exactly does the "+=" operator do?

Tags: c++

I already know that `x += 1` means `x = x + 1`.
The `=`-symbol allocates the value of the arithmetic expression on it's right to the variable on it's left.
But if i have an expression like `x += y % 3`, does that mean `x = (x + y) % 3`or `x = x + (y % 3)`?
The `+=` operator is both allocating a value to a variable and expressing arithmatics, which has me confused.

Unfortunately I currently can't just test some code to check, so I hope I can get some help here.
I'm new to C++, so some of these very basic things still confuse me...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Not being able to write code to check is fair. But if you are able to write an SO post, surely you can lookup [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `%` has higher precedence, so `x += y % 3` is `x += (y % 3)`, which increases `x` by `y % 3`.

Comment: "_But if i have an expression like `x += y % 3`, does that mean `x = (x + y) % 3` or `x = x + (y % 3)`?_" Your expression doesn't have parenthesis, so it does `x = x + y % 3`. Order in which each operation is performed is governed by operator precedence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a clear, well-documented textbook question, and should not be a question stack overflow.

Comment: It's not a text replacement. `x += e` means "add the value of `e` to the variable `x`, and your `e` is `y % 3`. (Note that precedence does not matter; `x *= 2 + 3;` is `x = x * (2 + 3)`, not `x = x * 2 + 3`.)

Comment: Quoting K&R 
"`expr1 = (expr1) op (expr2)`
except that `expr1` is computed only once. Notice the parentheses around `expr2`:

   `x *= y + 1`
means

   `x = x * (y + 1)`"

Comment: When it comes to the compound operators such as `+=`, `-=`, `^=` etc. The one thing that you have to remember is this: The entire right hand side is evaluated before the assignment happens. So when you look at the right hand expression, the most important thing to remember is operator precedence (the order of operations). You can always find a table of C++'s operator precedence. As for being able to write & compile code to test, there are various online compilers today; this is what Google is for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The `=`-symbol allocates the value of the arithmetic expression on it's right to the variable on it's left

It *assigns* the result. Allocation is something different, and it'll be important to remember the difference later (dynamic allocation in particular will be really confusing if you conflate it with assignment).

> But if i have an expression like `x += y % 3`, does that mean `x = (x + y) % 3` or `x = x + (y % 3)`?

Part of the reason for having the compound `+=`, `-=` etc. operators is that you *don't* expand the expression like this, avoiding the ambiguity created by your re-write.

```
x += y % 3
```

can be read as

```
tmp = y % 3; // evaluate right hand side
x += tmp;    // assign to left hand side
```

(you can expand `x += tmp` to `x = x + tmp` if you really want to, *after* `tmp` has been evaluated).

The rules are all documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in any case, and anyway you absolutely *can* just test some code to check:  https://ideone.com/81tvjH

Answer (score 2):

There is a confusion here, because you think `x += 1;` is always `x = x + 1`. This is true for integers, doubles... but generally NOT the case for other objects. Lots of implementations don't create a temporary object. Or could do something very evil.

So then it's a call to `operator+=`, which takes as the argument the result of the right hand side of the assignment.

So for integers, it's `x = x + (y % 3)`.

Comment: `x += 1` should always be **semantically** equivalent to `x = x + 1`. Anything else is just evil.

Comment: @SergeyA agreed, it should be equivalent unless you are already rotting in hell.